# Is it recommended to move a directory to the filesystem root partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem

When I installed the OS, I gave the partition that would be used for the root filesystem more space than would be needed.

34/50 GB is currently free while my `/home/{user_name}` partition is almost full.

Anaconda3 takes up 7GB and I want to move it to the partition that hosts the root filesystem, but is it advised to move such directories to that partition?

Comment: Filesystem root way  What does this mean?

Comment: @David It contains system related files and directories like `bin`, `usr`, `var` etc. Mounted on `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, my own preference is to avoid moving things around this way, but there is no iron rule which says that you must not.

If you move this directory, you must be aware of some pitfalls:

- A full partition can become unbootable if the log messages cannot be flushed to disk.
- Moving your Anaconda3 installation will affect your `$PATH` and possibly also your `$PYTHONPATH`

You may want to move the directory, and then create a symbolic link in the old location which targets the new location.

Comment: About Anaconda, I checked it up and they recommend to clone your existing environment, uninstall & re-install Anaconda and restore your environment.

The first risk you have mentioned was my main concern for this, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing in `/` that you add yourself should be mountpoints.

There is one directory in root that is defined as 3rd party software that you could mis-use for your system. Create a dir in `/opt/`, set it to your user and you can store your documents there. `/opt/` will be part of `/`.

Consider adding a partition(/mountpoint) though since that is more in line with a regular setup.

Comment: Yes I know that adding a partition or expanding the current one is better, the problem is I have both Windows and Linux on a 256 SSD, didn't have the budget for something else back then.